# Different execution time for Static table vs InnoDB table

Tags: mysql

How come result of a query with static table differs a lot in execution time, compared to same data as an InnoDB table?

Static table:

```
WITH calendar AS (
  SELECT '2022-05-01 00:00:00' s, '2022-05-02 00:00:00' e
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-05-02 00:00:00' s, '2022-05-03 00:00:00' e
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-05-03 00:00:00' s, '2022-05-04 00:00:00' e
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2022-05-04 00:00:00' s, '2022-05-05 00:00:00' e
  UNION ALL
  ...
)
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN huge_table ON huge_table.end_date >= s AND huge_table.start_date < e
GROUP BY huge_table.group_id
```

InnoDB table:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM calendar # contains same data as above static table
LEFT JOIN huge_table ON huge_table.end_date >= s AND huge_table.start_date < e
GROUP BY huge_table.group_id
```

The execution time for static table is almost twice as much as for the InnoDB table.

Comment: Start by looking at the EXPLAIN output for your two queries.

Comment: @nnichols exact same result in explain. Only difference is for column "table" where is says "calendar" for InnoDB example and "<derived2>" for static table.

Comment: I've also tried casting the dates in static table with the same result: CAST('2022-05-01 00:00:00' as DATETIME) s

Comment: Please add the EXPLAIN output for each query (as markdown tables) and the execution time. How many rows are you UNIONing in your CTE? Why are you joining to your CTE if you are not using it in the query? The CTE will have a very small overhead in creating the temporary table but this is normally negligible (less than 0.001s).